# Is there a keyboard shortcut to "untab" (move a block of code to the left) in Eclipse or Aptana Studio?

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana, zend-studio

It's so easy to select a block of code and tab out, but how about the reverse?

Currently, I just search and replace for white space at the beginning of the line. Is there anything faster?

Answer (score 576, accepted):

In Visual Studio and most other half decent IDEs you can simply do <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. It does the opposite of just <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

I would think and hope that the IDEs you mention support this as well.

Comment: Xcode is slightly different, uses COMMAND-[ and COMMAND-]

Comment: For any future folks who end up here via a Google search, this also works in Github's Atom IDE.

Comment: Fine also in IntelliJ

Comment: SHIFT+TAB works for Android Studio as well. Thanks !

Comment: Works in VSCode

Comment: Works fine in Sublime as well.

Comment: android studio too

Comment: Works in Notepad++

Comment: Likewise in PyCharm

Comment: " Ctrl+[ " will work for VScode not "shift+tab". at least in my case

Comment: Works in Anypoint Studio

Comment: Works in RStudio as well, many thanks!

Comment: Also works with Mui Components :)

Answer (score 23):

Shift-tab outdents again :)

The standard shortcut keys are covered in *[Standard Accelerators](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Standard_Accelerators)*.

You'll find many of the more esoteric ones on *[FAQ What editor keyboard shortcuts are available?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_editor_keyboard_shortcuts_are_available%3F)*.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a general answer for untab:

In Python [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

In Eclipse: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

In [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio): <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: The IDLE one is an example of one that is only suited for an [American keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#Windows_keyboards). E.g., Shift + AltGr + 8 is just not practical.

Answer (score 8):

In general, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> works for any environment.

Answer (score 6):

This workaround works most of the time. It uses Eclipse's 'smart insert' features instead:

1. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to erase the selected block of text, and keep it for pasting.
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to open a new line for editing above the one you are at.
3. You might want to adjust the tabbing position at this point. This is where tabbing will start, unless you are at the beginning of the line.
4. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste back the buffer.

I hope this helps until <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> is implemented in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> does that in [Flex Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Builder) (based on Eclipse), so it hopefully should work in regular Eclipse :)

Answer (score 5):

In [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs), just use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move a block of code left.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in PyCharm: Shift + Tab works fine.

Comment: Works in Vscode too!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by going to the *Window* menu → *Preferences*, and then open the *General* list. Choose *Keys*.

Scroll down the list of keys until you see "Shift Left". Click that. Below that, you'll see some boxes, one of which lets you bind a key. It won't accept <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so I bound it to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>. Apply <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>Close</kbd>, and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can do this in VS Code & Same works in most of IDE with the help of Shift + Tab.

Process :

a) Select the code you want to take one tab back.
b) Press **SHIFT** + **TAB**

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the shortcut. Use the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> shortcuts to open the *Keyboard Shortcut* menu. Search for the "tab" and find the "outdent" in the list.

Comment: On a [crapple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) device?