# How to move a block of code to the left in text editors / ide

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text 3 and Visual Studio 2013, I'd like to know if it's possible and how one would be able to highlight a block of code and move or drag it to the left. This would be the opposite of highlighting a few lines of code and hitting the tab button to shift them to the right. Is it a shortcut, a macro, a simple general thing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052772/keyboard-shortcut-to-untab-move-a-block-of-code-to-the-left-in-eclipse-apt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Sublime Text, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to move lines or blocks of text to the right, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to move to the left.

Answer (score 0):

In windows/linux, the shortcut is `Ctrl+[or]`

In Mac, the shortcut is `Command+[or]`