# What is the Keyboard shortcut to “untab” in Atom Editor?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

When we select lines and hit `tab`, it moves it to right.
How do we do the opposite (move left by tab spaces) ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Atom and [in most IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052772/keyboard-shortcut-to-untab-move-a-block-of-code-to-the-left-in-eclipse-apt?rq=1) you can untab by hitting `SHIFT` and `TAB`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for comment lines. Any idea how to untab in that case? Using backspace only removes one space at a time, and using `Ctrl`+`backspace` removes too much.

Answer (score 9):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to decrease the indentation and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (which is similar as <kbd>tab</kbd>) to increase the indentation. Same is valid in other editors as well.